# Xcode 10.4 vs Xcode 11 new libraries?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, xcode10

I am getting this errors from a project that is supposed to work straight away.

Because I am working from a lab, the current version is Xcode 10.4 while this work has been done on Xcode 11. Can you tell me if those classes are introduced from Xcode 11 onwards? If so, is there any workaround without needing me to update the software since I can't do it in the lab?

Xcode it's complaining about UIWindowSceneDelegate, UIScene etc.

[image: Errors screenshot]

Comment: Yes, all of the new scene delegate classes were introduced in iOS 13 and Xcode 11

Comment: Install Xcode 11 in the lab: you can perfectly have multiple installations of Xcode on the same machine: just name them differently. For instance, Xcode10.app and Xcode11.app